# Self-contained deplyoments with .net core under windows/iis

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

As I understood the documentation, when compiling a .net core 2.1 or higher application the system will take the latest installed SDK on the machine.

We are hosting out application under windows/iis therefore as a self contained application and therefore we also need to install the associated the hosting bundle for IIS.

Let's suppose the following scenario:

1. MyWebApp 1.0 based on SDK 2.2.102 / Runtime 2.2.1 is Released and deployed into PROD
2. Time passes by and the Team continues to Develop MyWebApp for 2.0 and upgrades to SDK 2.2.104 / Runtime 2.2.2
3. A bug in MyWebApp 1.0 is detected and it needs to be fixed and deployed with MyWebApp 1.1

Now since the Team has already installed a newer SDK if I would do a deployment of MyWebApp 1.1 it would also require to update the SDK on the windows machine.

Is it somehow possible to tell dotnet publish or in the csproj file to target another sdk?

Comment: It sounds like you want to look into [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that you should look into the [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json). Essentially this is a json file which allows you to "pin" the source code to a specific version of the SDK when building.

There are some downsides to this, though. the biggest being the speed at which Microsoft are releasing updates to the SDK. If you pin a code base to version 2.1.202 of the SDK (which is released as version 2.0.9), then you'll be using an end of life version of the SDK.